# Comparing NSDate + Period

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have start date and a duration (period). For example `startDate = '2014-02-12'` `period = 2`. I desired dates `2014-02-12`, `2014-02-14`, `2014-02-16`, .... I need to determine the current date is flagged during.

Comment: Can you add some sample code please?

Comment: Is the start date given as NSDate or NSString? What have you tried? What do you mean by "current date is flagged" ?

Comment: The start date given as NSDate. If the current date is equal to 2014-02-12, 2014-02-14, 2014-02-16, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the difference between the start date and the current date is an even
number of days, use `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *diff = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate
                                  toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSInteger days = diff.day;
if (days % 2 == 0) {
    // even number of days between start date and current date
}
```

Comment: Note that, `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` method truncates the results of the calculation to the smallest unit supplied. For instance, if the fromDate: parameter corresponds to Jan 14, 2010 at 11:30 PM and the toDate: parameter corresponds to Jan 15, 2010 at 8:00 AM, there are only 8.5 hours between the two dates. If you ask for the number of days, you get 0, because 8.5 hours is less than 1 day. There may be situations where this should be 1 day. You have to decide which behavior your users expect in a particular case.

Comment: Check out my answer, if you need days between two dates, as the number of midnights between.

Comment: @lancy: You are right that I have assumed that `startDate` is the *beginning* of the first day (at 00:00). If that is not the case than it can easily be achieved with `[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&beginningOfStartDate interval:NULL forDate:startDate];` .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired dates using

`- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds`

with `seconds = period*3600*24`

Comment: No. Not every day has 24 hours. Think of daylight saving time transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Calc the days from startDate to givenData, check the result whether it can be divisible by the period.

```
+ (NSInteger)daysWithinEraFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    // for timezone issue
    NSDate *newDate1 = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
    NSDate *newDate2 = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
    NSInteger startDay = [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                            inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:newDate1];
    NSInteger endDay = [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                          inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:newDate2];
    return endDay - startDay;
}
```